# What is the key circuitry in a form of high frequency signal generator that means power would be sent and reflected when there's an open load

Tags: rf, switches, signal, transmission-line, high-frequency

Ive asked enough questions to explain why when there is an impedance mismatch there is power reflected which from my understanding is because there is a reflection of the waves, and also the cause of the impedance in the first place along transmission lines is due to equivalent capacitance and inductance along the trace.

But id like to know what causes the original 'source impedance' in the first place, or specifically what is it in the circuitry that means if a very high impedance out of it (ie disconnection) leads to power been sent, to then be reflected.

Comment: You seem to mix different questions into one sentence. It's difficult to answer. Maybe you could try to separate them into at least individual paragraphs.

Comment: George, You say that reflection *"now makes sense"* when *"there is an impedance mismatch"*. Why don't you start be sharing with us how it is that this makes sense to you, and why. This would give us a leg-up on a better understanding of the rest of the question.

Comment: @periblepsis hopefully that helped where my understanding is at

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what causes the original 'source impedance' in the first place

The IV characteristic of the source.

If the source maintains constant voltage when we draw an arbitrary current from it, like an ideal power supply would, then we say it has zero output impedance.

If the source delivers a constant current, whatever voltage we set its output to, like a current source would, then we say it has infinite output impedance.

If the source voltage drops as we draw current, then it has a finite output impedance. If it drops by 1 V when we draw 20 mA, then the output impedance is 1 V / 20 mA = 50 ohms.

Some RF signal generators are implemented as a fed-back amplifier designed to have zero output impedance, followed by a real 50Ω resistor to define a nice clean 50Ω output impedance. It's so important to have a well defined source impedance, that the designers are prepared to 'waste' so much of that precious RF power in a series resistor, just to get the right output impedance.

> what is it in the circuitry that means if a very high impedance out of it (ie disconetion) leads to power been sent, to then be reflected.

A transmission line propagates a voltage wave, and a current wave, in lockstep. Their ratio is a property of the line itself, its geometry and dielectric and magnetic environment, and is called the characteristic impedance of the line.

If the line is connected to a line of a different impedance, then there is a discontinuity at the junction, you can't have a forward wave with an I and V ratio that matches both impedances. BUT, if you add a third wave at the junction, with voltage and current just right to take up the mismatch, then the equations can balance.

Just why or how this mathematical necessity 'generates' a reflected wave is either obvious, or bizarre, depending on your mindset, but it just does. It's part of the [unreasonable effectiveness of mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Unreasonable_Effectiveness_of_Mathematics_in_the_Natural_Sciences)

Comment: That really helped, im assuing that 50ohm mentioned is in series? And so if i simply had a signal generator like an ac source at v high frequency, and a 50ohm resitor in series, i supose this would also have a 50ohm impedance, but would this also cause reflection when there is no load attached? (specifically would this open load still cause the power to be sent in the first place to be then reflected?) hope that makes a little sense

Comment: @Georgekirby if you 'simply' had 'a' signal generator at v high frequency, it would probably be 50 ohms output impedance. If you then put a 50 ohm resistor in series, that would raise it to 100 ohms output impedance. 'No load attached' is inifinite load impedance, so you would get 100% reflection, regardless of the value of your finite output impedance.

Answer (score 0):

The source impedance is an intrinsic property of the device emitting EM power. An undamped oscillator will have some typical impedance mainly derived from L and C in it. Its impedance is of course complex.

And an open end of a transmission line is just a special case of a mismatch. It's the opposite of a shorted end of a transmission line. Both will reflect 100% but with opposite phase.